# Tag Page Redirecting to Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, blogs, tagging

We have some posts on our Wordpress website and we wanted to put tags on the bottom, so I used:

```
<p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
```

And it worked sort of.  The problem is it links to for example:

http://website.com/tag/foo

But that just shows the home page (/tag/foo doesn't exist).  How do I get my tags to list articles/posts with that tag or some sort of search/category view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a tag page set in your theme? It sounds like its defaulting to the index.php. See the order here, #5 is index.php: http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates.

Do you have a tag.php file?

Comment: No I do not.  How do I make it?

Comment: Is this a theme you created or a theme that you purchased/downloaded?

Comment: Oh okay I get it.  Some intern made it a while back I guess.  Thanks!